# wxWidgets: Memory error upon closing custom modal dialog

Tags: c++, exception, memory, wxwidgets

I've read [this](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Avoiding_Memory_Leaks), but I still don't understand what I did wrong with the code.

Here's the `bmNewFromImageDialog.h`, the class that extends `wxDialog`.

```
#ifndef BMNEWFROMIMAGEDIALOG_H
#define BMNEWFROMIMAGEDIALOG_H

#include "./../utils/includer.h" // includes a bunch of wx-related files
class bmNewFromImageDialog : public wxDialog {
public:
    wxBoxSizer *mainVBox, *flagHBox, *OKCancelHBox;
    wxStaticBox *flagsSBox;
    wxButton *OKButton, *cancelButton;
    wxRadioButton *GT0RadioButton;

    bmNewFromImageDialog() {}
    bmNewFromImageDialog(wxWindow *parent);

    void init();
};

#endif
```

Here's the `bmNewFromImageDialog.cpp`.

```
#include "./bmNewFromImageDialog.h"
#include "./../utils/includer.h"

bmNewFromImageDialog::bmNewFromImageDialog(wxWindow *parent) : wxDialog(parent, -1, wxT("new image..."), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize) {
    init();
}

void bmNewFromImageDialog::init() {
    mainVBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    flagHBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    OKCancelHBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    flagsSBox = new wxStaticBox(this, -1, wxT("Color flags"), wxPoint(0, 0), wxDefaultSize);
    GT0RadioButton = new wxRadioButton(this, -1, wxT(">0: 3 channels"), wxPoint(0, 0));
    flagsSBox->AddChild(GT0RadioButton);
    flagHBox->Add(flagsSBox, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxTOP | wxBOTTOM, 10);

    OKButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_OK, wxT("OK"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, 40));
    cancelButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_CANCEL, wxT("cancel"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, 40));
    OKCancelHBox->Add(OKButton, 1);
    OKCancelHBox->Add(cancelButton, 1, wxLEFT, 5);

    mainVBox->Add(flagHBox, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxTOP | wxBOTTOM, 10);
    mainVBox->Add(OKCancelHBox, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxBOTTOM, 10);
    SetSizer(mainVBox);
    Center();
}
```

and this is how I use the dialog in code:

```
bmNewFromImageDialog *newDialog = new bmNewFromImageDialog(this);
newDialog->ShowModal();
delete newDialog;
```

I constantly get an unhandled memory exception error at runtime when I close / click OK / click Cancel on that `bmNewFromImageDialog`. How should I fix this?

**EDIT**

@sir-digby-chicken-caesar I tried the `.Destroy()` and the stack solution, but there's still the same error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flagsSBox = new wxStaticBox(this, -1, wxT("Color flags"), wxPoint(0, 0), wxDefaultSize);
GT0RadioButton = new wxRadioButton(this, -1, wxT(">0: 3 channels"), wxPoint(0, 0));
flagsSBox->AddChild(GT0RadioButton);
//         ^^^^^^^^ this looks very wrong
```

That call is undocumented, and marked as "implementation mostly" in the header file. Do not use that unless you really know what you are doing.

It looks like your code should work if you just create `GT0RadioButton` with `flagsSBox` as its parent (remove the `AddChild` call).

Take a look at `wxStaticBoxSizer` too.

Comment: Thanks! This worked by just commenting out that line.

Answer (score 0):

This block:

```
bmNewFromImageDialog *newDialog = new bmNewFromImageDialog(this);
newDialog->ShowModal();
delete newDialog;
```

Should be changed to this:

```
bmNewFromImageDialog *newDialog = new bmNewFromImageDialog(nullptr);
newDialog->ShowModal();
newDialog->Destroy();
```

Never call `delete` on a wx widget class. If you need to deallocate a widget, remove it from the parent hierarchy, detach it from any sizer that uses it then call `Destroy();`

**Edit:**

As pointed out by user VZ and the [wxWidgets  documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_dialog.html), modal dialogs are one of the few wx widget classes that don't need to be created on the heap. So you could just create the dialog on the stack and let the destructor handle cleanup for you once the object goes out of scope:

```
bmNewFromImageDialog newDialog = bmNewFromImageDialog(nullptr);
newDialog.ShowModal();
```

Comment: Correct, but creating the dialog on the stack instead of on the heap would be even simpler and better.

Comment: True. I always forget that modal dialogs are one of the few wxWidgets windows that don't need to be created on the heap.